# ¿Cómo mostrar la tabla solo cuando se ingrese un dato en el buscador?

Tags: javascript, html

Como hago que la tabla me muestre los datos solo cuando se ingrese un valor en el campo de búsqueda? no se si me explico bien, pasa lo siguiente, cuando en el campo de búsqueda no hay nada, me muestra todos los datos de la tabla, lo que busco es que cuando el campo de búsqueda este vació me muestre solo la tabla vacía.

Esta es la tabla

```html
<table class="table table-bordered" id="mytable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Nombre</th>
                      <th>Edad</th>
                      <th>Telefono</th>
                      <th>Correo electronico</th>
                      <th>Profesion</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>

                  <?php while ($mostrar = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {?>

                    <tr>
                      <td><?php echo $mostrar['Seniors_nombre'] ." ". $mostrar['Seniors_Apellido1'] ." ". $mostrar['Seniors_Apellido2']?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $mostrar['Seniors_Edad'] ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $mostrar['Seniors_Telefono'] ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $mostrar['Seniors_Correo'] ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $mostrar['Seniors_Profesion'] ?></td>
                    </tr>

                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
```

Y este es el `script` que hace el `filtro`

```
<script>
   // Write on keyup event of keyword input element
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#search").keyup(function(){
   _this = this;
   // Show only matching TR, hide rest of them
   $.each($("#mytable tbody tr"), function() {
   if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($(_this).val().toLowerCase()) === -1)
   $(this).hide();
   else
   $(this).show();
   });
   });
  });
  </script>
```

Captura por si es necesario

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Podrias añadir una clase a tu tbody algo como tbody class="className"  y buscar esa clase en tu script para ocultarlo

```
  <tbody  class="className">

                  <?php while ($mostrar = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {?>

                    <tr>
                      <td><?php echo $mostrar['Seniors_nombre'] ." ". $mostrar['Seniors_Apellido1'] ." ". $mostrar['Seniors_Apellido2']?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $mostrar['Seniors_Edad'] ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $mostrar['Seniors_Telefono'] ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $mostrar['Seniors_Correo'] ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $mostrar['Seniors_Profesion'] ?></td>
                    </tr>

                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
     </tbody>
```

Y tu script algo como esto

```
<script>
   // Write on keyup event of keyword input element
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#search").keyup(function(){
   _this = this;
   // Show only matching TR, hide rest of them
   $.each($("#mytable tbody tr"), function() {
   if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($(_this).val().toLowerCase()) === -1)
   $('.className').hide();
   else
   $(this).show();
   });
   });
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: si ya lo resolví de esa manera ocultando la tabla